# A container with relative position and overflow hidden doesn't get a height

Tags: html, css

I've got the following piece of CSS in which i want the navigation and the website to be absolutely positioned so i can slide them back and forth when the menu button i pressed(Like the facebook app for example). To do so i've got a container with an `overflow: hidden`(To hide the nav bar and slide it in when needed). However; the container loses it's autoheight because of the absolute positioning within i'm afraid.

How can i get the height to be set automatically again as `overflow: hidden` does without absolute positioning in it.

i've created a fiddle in which the container has a height of 500px. I want to make the height scale automatically though. http://jsfiddle.net/rB7EY/

```
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 60em;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    background: grey;
        height: 500px;
}

    /*CSS for the navigation bar that can be toggled*/
     .navigation {
        width: 15em;
        float: left;
        background: blue;
        position: absolute;
        left: -20px;
    }

    /*The CSS for the actual content*/
     .website {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
    }

            .container .website .top_bar {
                height: 4em;
                background: pink;
                padding: 1em;
                position: relative;
            }

                .container .website .top_bar .menu_button {
                    width: 3.2em;
                    height: 2.5em;
                    background: red;
                    border: 0px;
                }


    nav.menu {
        width: 15em;
        position: absolute;
        left: 1em;
        top: 3em;
        background: yellow;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, enough you want to scale the container automaticly? Try using a min-height and a max-height

Comment: But i don't know, nor want to know specific heights. It just has to scale along with the content. Such as `overflow: hidden` would do if the divs within weren't absolutely positioned.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using a div between the container and the navigation and website and gave that a absolute position. With that i've decided to make the container be `min-width: 100%`